# how to get data using dropdownlist, textbox and search button in jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I want to display data using jsp,javascript and mysql. My Q. is If i select an entry suppose 'title' from dropdownlist and give a title name 'partial dif' in textbox and click on search button it should show me all the title names that starts with the letters '....par'. Please help me ...........

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. Break down the requirement in smaller steps. At which step exactly are you stucking while implementing the requirement accordingly? Displaying the dropdown values? Gathering the submitted values? Creating the SQL query? Executing the SQL query? Displaying the results? Etc. Also, how exactly is JavaScript related to this? What exactly would you do with JavaScript? Aren't you confusing JSP scriptlets with JavaScript?

Comment: There's no question here. If you want others to do work for you, this is not the place.

Answer (score 1):

suppose u have files named form.jsp, form1.jsp... and a table your_table with columns type and name.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>form.jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="form1.jsp" method="post" name=frm>
        <select name="list">
            <option>title</option>
            <option>author</option>
            <option>publication</option>
        </select>
        Name<input type="text" name=txt value=""/>
        <input type="submit" vaue="GO"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

form2.jsp

```
    <%String list1=request.getParameter("list");
         String name=request.getParameter("txt");
         name1=name.substring(0,3);
          Connection con;
                 PreparedStatement ps,ps1,ps2;
                 ResultSet rs,rs2;
       try{
                 String driverName="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
                 String url="jdbc:odbc:rail";
            String username="root";
            String password="root";
            Class.forName(driverName);
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
             ps=con.prepareStatement("Select name from your_table where type=? and name like ?%);
             ps.setString(1,list1);
             ps.setString(2,name1);
             rs=ps.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next())
             {
               out.println(rs.getString(1));
               }

            }
         catch(Exception e)
         {out.println(e);}   
%>
```